# How to call action method on selection of dropdown using razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
<select id="TypeOfUser" name="typeOfUser" class="active text-normal">
     <option value="2" onclick="location.href='@(Url.Action("Index", "User", new { typeOfUser = 2}))'">CMS Users</option>
     <option value="3" onclick="location.href='@(Url.Action("Index", "User", new { typeOfUser = 3}))'">Site Users</option>
</select>
```

on selection of dropdown item I want to call my action method with selected value-

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromQuery] int typeOfUser = 2)
{
   SearchUsersResponse searchUserResponse = await new SearchUsersHandler(_db).Handle(new SearchUsersCommandAsync
   {
       Type = typeOfUser
   });

   return View("Index", searchUserResponse);
}
```

Currently on dropdown selection change I am not able to call action method.

Comment: You are already using javascript (what do you think `onclick` is)

Comment: AFAIK, select element won't be able to call any action method itself without an event trigger, you need to set onchange event by JS/jQuery and submitting changed value to pass it as parameter value on the controller side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick` won't work on the option. What you can do is execute your javascript code for redirecting on the `onchange` event of the SELECT element.

```
<select id="TypeOfUser" name="typeOfUser" class="active text-normal" 
                                       onchange="doIt(this,'@Url.Action("Index", "User")')">
    <option value="2" >CMS Users</option>
    <option value="3">Site Users</option>
</select>
```

Assuming you have a javascript method which has 2 parameters. The first parameter is a reference to the SELECT element on which the onchange event occurred. So you can access the `value` property to get the selected option's value.

```
function doIt(item,baseUrl) {
        window.location.href = baseUrl + '?typeOfUser=' + item.value;
}
```